# Entry in /etc/group file

Tags: oncreate

In the /etc/group file, after kernel is boot. If we cat /etc/group file, we see that there are some default group names like haldaemon, shadow, sshd ....

Does everyone know who creates these groups in /etc/group file?

Answer (score 0):

Many processes on your system use their own usernames and groups, to intentionally restrict their permissions to only files they should be modifying.  This is a security and data integrity feature.  The vendor of your OS added these to your system during it's installation, or another software package added them to facilitate it's operation.

Comment: Do you know where the kernel source adding these or which package added them?

Comment: User groups are usually user space programs, because all kernel space programs are privileged, the programs in user space creating the groups will vary by distro.

sshd: The remote shell daemon created when you installed sshd.
shadow: The login system uses this to hash passwords.
haldaemon: Linux Hardware Abstraction subsystem daemon.